# php closures: why the 'static' in the anonymous function declaration when binding to static class?

Tags: php, closures, bind

The example in the php documentation on `Closure::bind` include `static` on the anonymous function declaration. why? I can't find the difference if it is removed.

**with**:

```
class A {
    private static $sfoo = 1;
}
$cl1 = static function() { // notice the "static"
    return self::$sfoo;
};
$bcl1 = Closure::bind($cl1, null, 'A');
echo $bcl1(); // output: 1
```

**without**:

```
class A {
    private static $sfoo = 1;
}
$cl1 = function() {
    return self::$sfoo;
};
$bcl1 = Closure::bind($cl1, null, 'A');
echo $bcl1(); // output: 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've noticed, it doesn't really matter.

It's like using the `static` keyword on a class method. You don't necessarily *need* it if you don't reference `$this` within the method (though this *does* violate strict standards).

I suppose PHP can work out you mean the `Closure` to access `A` statically due to the `null` 2nd argument to `bind()`

Comment: error_reporting is set to E_ALL and i didn't get any E_STRICT notices.

Comment: still no error. i tried `error_reporting(-1)` and error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT). i'm useing PHP 5.5.5

Answer (score 59):

I beg to differ.  It's true that often it won't matter.  But sometimes it matters *a whole lot*.

The closure holding a reference to `$this` might prevent garbage collection of that object, which in turn may also impact performance significantly.  Here's an example where it really makes a huge difference:

```
class LargeObject {
    protected $array;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->array = array_fill(0, 2000, 17);
    }

    public function getItemProcessor(): Closure {
        // Try with and without 'static' here
        return static function () {
            // do some processing unrelated to $this
        };
    }
}

$start = microtime(true);

$processors = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 2000; $i++) {
    $lo = new LargeObject();
    $processors[] = $lo->getItemProcessor();
}

$memory = memory_get_usage() >> 20;
$time = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;
printf("This took %dms and %dMB of memory\n", $time, $memory);
```

Here's the output with a normal closure:

```
This took 55ms and 134MB of memory
```

Here's the output with a static closure:

```
This took 22ms and 1MB of memory
```

I tested this with PHP 7.3.19 on Debian Buster, so YMMV.  Obviously this is a specially constructed example to demonstrate the difference.  But things like this may happen in real applications as well.  I started using Slevomat's [SlevomatCodingStandard.Functions.StaticClosure](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard) sniff to remind me to always use static closures.

Comment: 20000 iterations:

With static: This took 107ms and 7MB of memory / Without static: This took 545ms and 1338MB of memory 


At PHP 7.4.16 / linux mint (ubuntu beaver)

Comment: try it across various php version: https://3v4l.org/QnDuA, and it's still valid in php 8.1

Answer (score 45):

found the difference: you can't bind static closures to object, only change the object scope.

```
class foo { }

$cl = static function() { };

Closure::bind($cl, new foo); // PHP Warning:  Cannot bind an instance to a static closure
Closure::bind($cl, null, 'foo') // you can change the closure scope
```

Comment: +1 Good find; I had noticed that `$this` is unbound, but the fact that it *cannot* be bound is interesting.

Answer (score 23):

Static Closures, like any other static method, cannot access `$this`.

Like any other method, a non-static Closure that does not access `$this` will generally work in a static context.

Comment: can you provide a source of static closure's performance gain?

Comment: I'd also like to see the source of the performance imporvement and how measurable it might be in a codebase. For most of use the extra characters neeing parsed might not outweigh any performance gain.

Comment: I based the performance argument on hearsay, I since benchmarked it and it's negligible